# modify class of gridview element dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_patientMeds" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Both" OnRowDataBound="gv_patientMeds_onRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="lb_editPatient" runat="server" CssClass="<%# Eval(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("recordId")) != 0 ? "btn-active" : "btn-inactive"); %>" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="SubmitDeleteMedicationChange(<%# Eval("updateClinicVisit_recordIdForDelete") %>);" UseSubmitBehavior = "false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I load data into it like this:

```
gv_patientMeds.DataSource = theDataToBindInPopup;
gv_patientMeds.DataBind();
```

`theDataToBindInPopup` is just a list of custom objects.

As you can see I am attempting to assign the class of the delete button using some logic where recordId is a property of one of the objects in the DataToBindInPopup list. ASP doesn't like this though. I am getting "server tag in not well formed".

How can I assign the class of the button using logic in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what Ganesh and fnostro suggest you will works, you could also set your logic in code behind:

```
protected void gv_patientMeds_onRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {   
            //Get data row view
            DataRowView drview = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //Find dropdown control
                Button btn= (Button)e.Row.FindControl("lb_editPatient");
                btn.CssClass= Convert.ToInt32(drview["recordId"]) != 0 ? "btn-active" : "btn-inactive"; 

            }
        }
```

Comment: you can do this as the OP is trying to do...once you get the quotes correct :) however handling this in the RowDataBound event is far cleaner and offers much more control.

Comment: @fnostro should be nice, btw will work on OnClientClick but not on CssClass

Comment: it will and it does.  server side code is rendered first and end results will be class="X"  where "X" is one or the other css class...assuming the bound data doesn't throw an exception on the convert.  Your way is still better though

Comment: @fnostro mmmh :) , I am not completely sure, I will check now :)

Comment: I used your method though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace You `lb_editPatient` Button with this

Wrap Your Double Quotes Inside Single Quotes

```
<asp:Button ID="lb_editPatient" runat="server" 
CssClass='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("recordId")) != 0 ? "btn-active" : "btn-inactive") %>' Text="Delete" 
OnClientClick='SubmitDeleteMedicationChange(<%# Eval("updateClinicVisit_recordIdForDelete") %>)' UseSubmitBehavior = "false" />
```

Comment: Still getting the error "server tag is not well formed". You only removed the Eval() from the CssClass logic right?

Comment: it's your use of embedded double quotes.  Make sure your embedded code is surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: while you are probably right about that, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @fnostro Never mind my comment above. You were right. I also had the same problem on the OnClientClick argument.

Comment: @Byc Now updated Forgot To Include Single Quotes for `OnClientClick`

Comment: yes - same rules apply to all - for what it's worth the answer provided by InvernoMuto above is the proper/cleaner way - handling this as embedded code is not as good as handling it in the `RowDataBound` event.  This includes setting the OnClientClick event.